# Compilation error on a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, compiler-errors

I'm stumped!

We have a user control for managing account information. We use this particular control on two pages. On one page, everything works perfectly and meets our expectations. On the second page however we receive compilation errors stating that:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\lrpcentral\0e987bea\6719c8b6\App_Web_PageThatFails.aspx.f3d462c1.oi52bvii.0.cs(172): error CS0433: The type 'xxxx_ascx' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\APPLICATIONNAME\0e987bea\6719c8b6\App_Web_xxxx.ascx.cdcab7d2.xbnvt2za.dll' and 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\APPLICATIONNAME\0e987bea\6719c8b6\App_Web_eix7xllr.dll'

My problem is similar to [Cyril's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491046/asp-net-compilation-conflict-my-usercontrol-exists-in-two-locations) but the "delete everything from Temp" is not an option for me, and Cyril's solution does not apply since the only variable we have is contained in the designer file, which is not deployed to our production environment (we pre-compile).

After reading [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596118/asp-net-error-the-type-foo-exists-in-both-temp1-dll-and-temp2-dll-pt-2) I examined my directories for circular dependency and was unable to find any.

Structure:

Top Level >

**Page that works**

**Control**

*Directory A* >
    **Page that causes the error**

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: Does anyone know why this occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That occurs because two different assemblies referenced in your application contain the same namespace and type, which produces ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the bin in your production environment before deploying the pre-compiled files?